# Manually deleted a row in postgresql and now ActiveRecord is breaking

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

My Rails app is using ActiveRecord backed by Postgres. I went into the database through psql and deleted a row from one of the tables. In hindsight this was a terrible decision as it is causing parts of the app to crash that are trying to reference that object.

Things like:

```
undefined method `first_name' for nil:NilClass
```

Or

```
Couldn't find Person with id=137
```

So now I have two questions.

1. How do I fix this?
2. Is manipulating the data through `rails console production` the best way to manually update it? Or is should I avoid that too?

Example of code

```
Reward.all.order("created_at DESC").where(warning: false, created_at: @yearrange).page(params[:page])
```

Where Reward contains a reference to the Person id

Comment: Did you `delete from people where id = 137` perhaps?

Comment: Yes, Person with id 137 is most likely the object I deleted.

Comment: Put it back by hand or track down everything that references it and fix those dangling references. Then look at the foreigner gem and start using real FKs in the database so that the database can protect you from this sort of data corruption.

Comment: That is what I ended up doing. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to e.g. PHP, ruby/Rack applications such as Rails stay loaded in memory for use by subsequent requests. Chances are a reference to the old data is referenced in a cache somewhere. Try to get the app server to reload to fix.

A more likely culprit, that said, is memcached or similar if you use such a thing. Flush it as needed.

I'm not familiar enough with Rails to be sure on this last point, but I'd imagine the Rails console uses your app's code flow and flushes caches as needed when it does.

---

Note: as point out by @muistooshort in the comments, it might also be a dangling foreign key somewhere if you didn't create the FK cnstraints in your schema.

Comment: I have tried restarting the server, but it still happens. I don't believe the app is using a memcache (I didn't write the original project).

Comment: @Denis Eep, really? I'd want listen/notify based cache invalidation or something. Does it just blindly assume that nobody else will be messing with the same data at the same time?

Comment: I'd guess that there's a dangling FK somewhere because Rails thinks that "logic in the database" is bad and silly things like "data integrity through real FKs" count as "logic" (bad logic! bad! go sit in a corner!). Excuse me if I sound a bit bitter, being a database guy in Rails-land is difficult.

Comment: @CraigRinger: yeah. The assumption in Rails (and frameworks in other languages) is that the data is stored in a giant dictionary. For this reason, it also encourages you to write what belongs in triggers or SP over in your app.